# how to add Primary Key in ORMLITE android On Upgrade method?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

In my project I have used ORMLite. Now I added a primary key for
tje `accountId` field and also have changed DB Version. Please help me, I don't know how to write query in `onUpgrade(...)`.  For reference I
have attached `Account` class below.

```
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @DatabaseField
    private String cdate;

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private Integer accountId;

    @DatabaseField
    private String Type;

    @DatabaseField
    private String Desc;

    @DatabaseField
    private String UpdatedDate;
}
```

Comment: Can `accountId` be `null`?  If not then it should be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to write query in onUpgrade(...).

The trick is to figure out what Sqlite commands you need to make to add a primary key.  You can figure this out by looking at the [Sqlite docs for the primary key](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).  There you can see that your `accountId` field should be defined as:

```
accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC
```

So then your `onUpdate(...)` method should be something like:

```
if (version of db is the old-version) {
    dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE account ADD COLUMN accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC;");
}
```

You should do this conditionally based on the old version of the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already I added **accountId** column just need to add PRIMARY  KEY alone. But I fixed it by creating **new table** and copied from **old table** to **new table**.